# wordpress get_user_balance function issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i worked out a function like this:

```
function get_user_balance( $id ) {
global $wpdb;  
$row =  $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT balance FROM      
$wpdb->wp_users WHERE ID = %d", $id));
return $row;
}
```

Bizarrly it is not working when i am trying to get the balance:

```
$users_balance = get_user_balance($show_detail->user_id);
echo $users_balance;
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: $wpdb->get_row this will return array you have use print_r or var_dump to view the output

Comment: thanks, i just tried with print_r but seems not working. with var_dump the output is: NULL

Comment: Are you sure you have balance column in WP default user table? May you saved this balance in meta table of user

Comment: Ok now i figured it out, but now the outpout with print_r is:   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [balance] => 2.32 ) )     `$row =  $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT balance FROM `wp_users` WHERE `wp_users`.`ID` = %d", $id));
print_r($row);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_user_balance( $id ) {
global $wpdb;  
$row =  $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT balance FROM `wp_users` WHERE `wp_users`.`ID` = %d", $id));
print($row);
}
```

this works now for me!